# Как получить адрес перегруженной функции в clang

Tags: c++, clang

В visual_studio этот код отлично работает

```
template<class T>
class Interface{
  public:
    constexpr Interface() noexcept {
      static_cast<void>(&T::foo); // Проверка того, что в типе 'T' есть функция 'foo'
    }
};
```

Но вот в clang++ выдает ошибку

```
error : address of overloaded function 'foo' cannot be static_cast to type 'void'
```

Наверное, в clang нет поддержки такой фичи?

p.s. Вместо `void` подставлял `void*`, `void(*)()`, `long long`, `uintptr_t`. Пробовал также заменять `static_cast` на `reinterpret_cast` и на приведение в стиле си. Ничего не помогло.

p.p.s.

```
clang version 13.0.0
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Вместо `void` следует подставить требуемый тип `&T::foo`.

Comment: &T::foo это взятие адреса, но никак не тип

Comment: `&T::foo` это выражение, и, как у всякого выражения, у него есть тип. И этот тип надо указывать явно когда берется адрес перегруженной функции для выбора конкретной перегрузки.

Comment: Я пробовал, не работает